# Accessing a Pyqt5 TextEdit from another file

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have two python files, one called "myInterface.py" who contains the GUI made with PyQt5 and converted with pyuic5 and the other "functions.py"who do the operations.

The first one:

```
myMessage = None

def setMessage(message):
    myMessage = message
    Ui_Dialog.writeMessage(message)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(640, 560)
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 320, 291, 211))
        self.textEdit_2.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        #buttons, labels, etc
```

And inside the Ui_Dialog class i have this function:

```
def writeMessage(self,message):
    self.textEdit_2.append(message)
```

From the second file i try to write a message in the first one:

```
def checkDirectory(directory):
    os.chdir(directory)
    print("Checking folder")
    #here i want to send the message above
    myInterface.setMessage("Checking folder")
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'textEdit_2'
```

Comment: You named the method `writeMessage`, not `setMessage`.

Comment: You should ***never*** manually edit the file generated by `pyuic`. Please read [Using the Generated Code](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code) in the PyQt docs.  The second or third examples shown there are what you should be using.